# Scala: type mismatch when calling a method from generic trait

Tags: scala, generics

Let's look at some code first:

```
trait Foo[T] {
  def fooize(value : T) : Unit
}
object TestFoo {
  def testFooForType[T[_] <: Foo[_]](obj : T[Int]) {
    obj.fooize(5)
  }
}
```

Why doesn't it typecheck and how can I overcome this difficulty? What I want to do is to test any class that implements the given trait `Foo` for a particular type `T` (`Int` in the example).

Comment: I don't need `T` as such in the body of `testFooForType`, you might as well use simply `def testFooForType(obj: Foo[Int])`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`T[_] <: Foo[_]` 
means "T forSome type" extends "Foo forSome type".

It has to allow for cases where the types are different. (T[A] extends Foo[B])

Binding T with Int type has no effect on Foo's type, which is still unbounded.

You can either specify Foo's type:

```
def testFooForType[T[_] <: Foo[Int]](obj : T[_]) {
    obj.fooize(5)
}
```

or you can make the type relationship explicit:

```
def testFooForType[T[V] <: Foo[V]](obj : T[Int]) {
    obj.fooize(5)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was so focused on "T will just be a class extending trait Foo" that I didn't think about that.